# AES encrypted File transfer over TCP socket; padding issue

Tags: python, sockets, encryption, tcp

I'm trying to do a file transfer using encrypted TCP socket with AES 256.

- If I transfer a file without encryption, it works fine.
- If I send small commands (such as 'ipconfig') to the client or server, the encryption works fine.
- No matter the file size is, I keep receiving the following error message:

  ```
  DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/base64.py", line 76, in b64decode
      raise TypeError(msg)
  TypeError: Incorrect padding
  ```

My function for encoding and decoding is the following (the `hat` variable is the message):

```
def AESENC(hat,typ):

    BLOCK_SIZE = 32
    PADDING = '{'
    pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
    EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
    DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

    secret = '01234567890123456789012345678912'
    IV = 'wir&/>H54mgd9a";'

    cipher = AES.new(secret,AES.MODE_CFB,IV)

    if typ == 0:
        encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, hat)
        return encoded
    else:
        decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, hat)
        return decoded
```

**Client side**

```
if os.path.exists(df):
    print ' found the file '
    f = open(df, 'rb')
    packet = f.read(1024)
    while packet != '':
        s.send(AESENC(packet,0)) 
        s.send(   AESENC('123XXX',0)  ) 
    s.send('123XXX')
    f.close()
```

**Server side**

```
f = open('/root/Desktop/Transfer.mp3','wb')
while True:
    bits =  AESENC ( conn.recv(1024) , 1 )
    while (bits):
        f.write(bits)
        bits =  AESENC ( conn.recv(1024) , 1 )
        if bits.endswith('123XXX'):
            print '[+] Transfer completed '
            break

    f.close()
    break
return
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Oh hey, more crypto code with vulnerabilities.  You know that you should never reuse an initialization vector, right?  And you know that encryption does not provide authentication?

Comment: okay but how we can explain that the only the file transfer is not working ! , i mean when i execute a command in the CMD shell on the server side i can see it's encrypted in wireshark and it's being encrypted and decrypted fine on both side using same function

Comment: How are you sending & receiving the data? It looks like the base64 decoding step is failing, and in my experience this padding error means that you have an incorrect data length. Perhaps your data is being truncated somehow. Can you compare the data that is sent and received?

Comment: @Whatang , i have updated the code with client & server sides + the file size is 5.5 MB , i only receive 1.7 MB . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for the misunderstanding of your sample code, and thank you for adding the server and client calls!

Please note that the error message that you're getting is unrelated to the encryption.  You can read the relevant part of the base64.py library: the error message indicates that the base64 data is not valid.  In particular, it's not properly padded at the end.

With the additional call site information, I believe the problem is that you're encrypting *and then separately encoding* each 1024 byte block of the data on the client.  Then, on the server, you're reading 1024 bytes from the network and trying to decode it.  However, base64-encoding will increase the length of the original data, so what you'll read will only be the first 1024 bytes of the encoded form, which will be a truncated base64 message (hence improperly padded).

As for how to solve it, a base64 message needs to be decoded all as one piece.  So you either need to calculate how much data to read from the network to get a complete encoded block (a calculation that you can do reliably except for the possibly short last packet, since the base64 length is always (length + 2) / 3 * 4), encode the entire data stream at once (which is likely a problem due to memory use if you want to handle arbitrary-sized files), or define your network protocol so that the server can tell that it's seen a complete block that can be decoded with base64.

Comment: Thnx for your reply , yes i meant that . but even with passing the encoded mesage to 'DecodeAES(cipher, encoded)' i'm still facing the same problem. i will edit my code.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem. `hat` is the input string. In can potentially be the string to encrypt or the string to be decrypted.

Comment: @JeffMercado, thanks.  I had misunderstood the example.  I've revised my answer based on the updated code.  Thank you, Hussam, for the update, and apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: +1 this is the reason your code is failing. You're reading a kb from a file, base64 encoding it. When you base64 encode a string, you change its size (~40% increase IIRC). Your code doesn't take this into account.

Comment: @rra  + Morten , Thanks you guys for your explanation , but honestly I'm not sure how to solve it so what do i need to change in my code , i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384658/encryption-of-a-jpg-file-using-pycrypros-aes-failing

Comment: The simplest fix is to change the code that's reading the base64-encoded data from the network to read 1368 -- (1024 + 2) * 4 / 3 -- bytes at a time.  This will give you a complete chunk after the increase in size from base64 encoding.

Comment: @rra  i will try this and see , thnx

Comment: @rra i tired that and it worked fine with 1 condition if the file size is small such as 1 KB , for other files larger than this one , the transfer is completed however the file is courrpted for example if i transfer rar file when i extract its content it said CRC error/courrpted , same for mp3 or jpeg . any idea ?

Comment: I don't have a good idea off-hand.  I would compare the two files and see where they start to differ.  For example, do they differ on block boundaries?  Maybe my math is off and that isn't quite the right number of characters.  You could also take a look at the base64-encoded messages and be sure that they end with padding (generally `=` characters).  I think 1024 bytes will always require padding.

Comment: can you give a code example of how to decode all of the message in one piece